# creating a list of class objects to compare them with another class object

Tags: java, list, loops, instanceof, forge

First of all, sorry, this question might be answered already, but my searches didn't really tell me anything and i don't really know what I am searching for anyway.

Basically, I need to create a `List` of class objects (only store the class / don't store initialized objects - don't really know how to explain)and compare them to another class object (ala `instanceof`). But I have no idea how to do this.

An Example would be:

I want to do this:

```
if(something1 instanceof something2)
```

with a `List` of "something1's", to be able to iterate through it like this:

```
for(int i= 0 ; i <= list.size; i++) 
{
  if (list.get(i) instanceof something2)
    doSomething();
}
```

so I basically need to know how/what I have to store in the actual list to be able to do something like that.

Is this possible?

I hope this is somewhat understandable.

Comment: Yes it is. Use generic lists an the class "Class", something like List<Class>  classes = new ArrayList<Class>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare classes using `equals()` method, this method will check if the class is exactly the same.

So you first put classes in a list (assuming you have classes `Foo` and `Bar` and a list is `List<Class>`):

```
list.add(Foo.class);
```

And then you iterate over it and do comparison like this:

```
if (list.get(i).equals(Bar.class))
    doSomething();
```

Comment: thats exactly what i needed! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`Class` class provides API to do `instance of` like check:

```
Class numClass = Number.class;
List<Class> classes = Arrays.asList(Integer.class);
...
if (numClass.isAssignableFrom(classes.get(i))) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using generic lists and class Class:

```
List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
classes.add(Integer.class);
classes.add(String.class);
classes.add(MyClass.class);
//...

for (Class myClass : classes) {
    if (myClass.equals(MyOtherClass.class)) {
        doSomething(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List of classes can be declared as `List<Class> list`, e.g.

```
List<Class> classes = Arrays.asList(String.class, Number.class);
Class testedClass = Integer.class;
```

If you want to test the exact classes equality use `equals`.

```
for (Class clazz : list) {
    if (clazz.equals(testedClass)) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Or even shorter

```
if (list.contains(testedClass)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

But if you need an analogue of `instanceof` then use `isAssignableFrom`

```
for (Class clazz : list) {
    if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(testedClass)) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

`isAssignableFrom` means that `clazz` and `testedClass` are in the same hierarchy and `testedClass` extends or equals to `class`